# Замена ссылок во всей странице WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, replace

Стоит задача в сгенерированной странце (та, что показывается посетителю) автоматически заменять ссылки по правилам. 
Как это в Wordpress реализовать?

Я нашел вывод всей страницы в файле
'wp-includes/template-loader.php';
Т.е. там можно получать конечное содержимое и менять его. Но ребята из WordPress.com говорят, что так делать нельзя, потому что это изменение движка и при первом же обновлении будут проблемы.

Есть ли другие варианты?

Comment: 1. Что значит "по правилам" и что/где/ЗАЧЕМ заменять? В см почему и как "там" (непонятно где) неправильные. 2.В файлы движка не лезь!

Comment: Например, у меня в шаблоне и в тексте есть ссылка http://site.ru/img1.jpg, а мне надо заменить её на http://cdn.site.ru/img1.jpg. Как это сделать?

Comment: Я чет не вижу тут https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/template-loader.php строки site.ru/img1.jpg

Comment: Забудьте про файлы ядра. В ВП всё на фильтрах. Вам нужен https://wp-kama.ru/hook/the_content

Comment: the_content не поможет. Это лишь содержимое из базы. А мне надо ещё все пути шаблона менять. По сути - анализировать всё содержимое и менять одну ссылку на другую.

Comment: Пути шаблона в шаблоне поменяй. А лучше нормально опиши задачу.

Comment: В [шаблонах](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2) темы не должно быть никаких путей, не относящихся непосредственно к теме. И ещё раз: хочешь решить проблему - опиши нормально условия и задачу.

Comment: Я хочу сделать плагин, который будет заменять домен в ссылках "на лету". Причем домен должен меняться и в ссылках поста, и в ссылках темы. Будут существовать правила, по которым определяется, меняем ли в ссылке домен или нет (например, нужно поменять только ссылках изображений).

Comment: О каких ссылках темы ты говоришь? Что такое ссылка темы? Это пункт меню например? Или жестко прописанная ссылка в шаблоне?

Comment: Да, путь к CSS, например. Да и пусть он не жестко прописал. Пусть относительно. Как его заменять?

Comment: Какая конечная цель замен, зачем вам это?

Comment: Подсунуть ссылки для CDN

Comment: ob_start, str_replace

Comment: Я понимаю как сделать, вопрос - где модификацию проводить? В ядро лезть нельзя. Как быть тогда?

Comment: В functions.php например

Comment: Окей, и как это правильно сделать? functions.php чего ? (темы, плагина)

Comment: Мне кажется, что тебе стоит почитать документацию WP, хоть базовые вещи

Comment: Так про какие конкретно вещи почитать? На что обращать внимание?

Comment: 1. https://codex.wordpress.org/Создание_тем 2. https://codex.wordpress.org/Стандарты_кодирования_WordPress 3. https://codex.wordpress.org/Написание_плагина 4. https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API 5. https://codex.wordpress.org/Справочник_по_функциям  Для затравки